# How can I ensure that a Retrofit function is working only once

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I have an app with different API operations made with retrofit. Unfortunately, the API I am using doesn't have an update function so instead of updating, I am currently deleting, and adding with updated values.

This solution works OK when my update clicks are more than half a second apart, but when I click faster It causes duplications.

I am using Data Binding and MVVM. So, function call route is as following:
XML -> Fragment (Adapter in this case) -> ViewModel -> Repository

```
fun updateCartItem(cart: Cart) {
    apiService.deleteCartItem(cart.cartFoodId,cart.orderUsername).enqueue(object: Callback<CartResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<CartResponse>?, response: Response<CartResponse>?) {
            apiService.addFoodToCart(
                cart.foodName,
                cart.foodPicture,
                cart.foodPrice,
                cart.foodQuantity,
                cart.orderUsername
            ).enqueue(object: Callback<CartResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<CartResponse>?, response: Response<CartResponse>?) {
                    fetchCart(cart.orderUsername)
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CartResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {}
            })
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CartResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {}
    })
}
```

I tried to add @Synchronized annotation to my function, but it didn't help.

Basically what I need is a way to ensure my update function is working only once.

Comment: If you only want it to work *once*, you could add the ID to a `Set` of items being updated. When the user clicks the button, add the ID and do the API stuff. If the ID is already in the set, just ignore the button click. (You could remove the ID when the add request completes, so the next click will start a new update)

Comment: You could just use `var boolean isUpdating = false` in your ViewModel, set it to true when update started and to false after it finishes, Then check at the start of your updateCartItem function `if (isUpdating) return`